# Convert C# row to PHP

Tags: c#, php

I want to convert a C# row to PHP, but it doesn't work (the result isn't the same):

C#:

PHP:

Someone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: If you include the values of each expression rather than leaving us to guess, your question would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code should return the same result.

The only problem I can think of is that the type of data inside "$header[$i]" is a string and not an integer. This causes PHP to parse the ASCII code of $header[$i] instead of the value it is supposed to represent:

Intended result:

```
$xorKey = 16909060;
$data = 1337;

$data = ((16 * ($xorKey ^ (~$data & 0xFF)))
                 | (($xorKey ^ (~$data & 0xFF)) >> 4)) & 0xFF;

echo $data; // int 60
```

Whereas using a string results in the following:

```
$xorKey = 16909060;
$data = '1337'; // HERE BE DRAGONS

$data = ((16 * ($xorKey ^ (~$data & 0xFF)))
                 | (($xorKey ^ (~$data & 0xFF)) >> 4)) & 0xFF;

echo $data; // int 112
```

To remedy this:

```
$xorKey = 16909060;
$data = '1337';

$data = intval($data); // Parse this string as an integer.

$data = ((16 * ($xorKey ^ (~$data & 0xFF)))
                 | (($xorKey ^ (~$data & 0xFF)) >> 4)) & 0xFF;

echo $data; // int 60
```

Comment: Thanks.
I rewrote it after asking here and the problem was gone :D.